# Regular expression to count ALL newline characters in C++

Tags: c++, regex, flex-lexer, lex

I am trying to write a rules.l file to generate flex to read through any given input and print out every possible thing (for example - *string*, *int*, *+*, *-*, *if*, *else*, etc), along with its length, token, and what line it is on. Everything works as it should, except that it is not counting newline characters within a string literal.

I have googled my heart out and read all kinds of things, and they all say that just using the expression `\n` should allow me to count every newline in the text.

I also use `[ \t]` to eat whitespace.

My output *should* say:

```
< line: 14, lexeme: |"last"|
```

but instead it says:

```
> line: 10, lexeme: |"last"|
```

Any input/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Here is a bit of my .l file for context:

```
%option noyywrap
%{
int line_number = 1;
%}
%%
if                          { return TOK_IF; }
else                        { return TOK_ELSE; }
.
.
.
[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|"_")*   { return TOK_IDENTIFIER; }
\"(\\.|[^"\\])*\"               { return TOK_STRINGLIT; }


[ \t]+  ;

[\n]                                {++line_number;}
```

Comment: You can't use regexes to parse C++. Simple counter-example: `const char* str = "how about \"hello world\"?";`. Write a proper lexer; or, ideally, use one that already exists (this has been a solved problem for many decades).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings This is tokenizing, not parsing. I can't think of any reason regexes couldn't tokenize C++ if written carefully enough. (Raw string literals require a back-reference, but that's a feature of some common "regex" types.)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings: OP is, in fact, using a tokeniser which is designed to deal with these issues.

Comment: see also [When you should NOT use Regular Expressions?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/113237/98103)

Comment: When you say "my `driver.cpp` file", do you actually mean "the `driver.cpp` file which was given to me?" Because if it were *your* file, you could just change the name of the variable :-)

Comment: OK, added a couple of suggestions of where to look for uncounted newlines. Good luck. Frankly, I think it's a ridiculous requirement. (And you can tell your professor I said that.)

Comment: @phuclv Nothing in that link suggests that regular expressions shouldn't be used for tokenization. And even if someone had suggested such non-sense there, I'd trust the opinion of the authors of lex, flex and many other lexer generators, as well as those of the authors of virtually every book on compiler construction, over those of some random SE user. Regular expressions are perfect for lexical analysis which is why so many lexer generators are built around them.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you add

```
%option yylineno
```

to your Flex file, and then use the `yylineno` variable instead of trying to count newlines yourself. Flex gets the value right, and usually manages to optimise the computation.

That said, `\"([^"])*\"` is not the optimal way to read string literals, because it will terminate at the first quote. That will fail disastrously if the string literal is `"\"Bother,\" he said. \"It's too short.\""`

Here's a better one:

```
\"(\\(.|\n)|[^\\"\n])*\"
```

(That will not match string literals which included unescaped newline characters; in C++, those are not legal. But you'll need to add another rule to match the erroneous string and produce an appropriate error message.)

---

I suppose it is possible that you must conform to the artificial requirements of a course designed by someone unaware of the `yylineno` feature. In that case, the simple solution of adding `line_number = yylineno;` at the beginning of every rule would probably be considered cheating.

What you will need to do is what flex itself does (but it doesn't make mistakes, and we programmers do): figure out which rules might match text including one or more newlines, and insert code *in those specific rules* to count the newlines matched. Typically, the rules in question are multi-line comments and string literals themselves (since the string literal might include a backslash line continuation.)

One way to figure out which rules might be matching newlines is to turn on the `yylineno` feature, and then examine the code generated by flex. Search for `YY_RULE_SETUP` in that file; the handler for every parser rule (including the ones whose action does nothing) starts with that macro invocation. If you have enabled `%option yylineno`, flex figures out which rules might match a newline, and inserts code before `YY_RULE_SETUP` to fix `yylineno`. These rules start with the comment `/* rule N can match eol */`, where `N` is the index of the rule. You'll need to count rules in your source file to match `N` with the line number. Or you can look for the `#line` directive in the generated code.